# dartboard/circle detection (off angle) python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, detection

I want to detect a dartboard live on cam but the cam is in a off angle. Because of this I'm not sure that I can use cv2.HoughCircles and might have overcomplexed my code. This is my first time image proccesing. But currently my code detects to much background stuff and doesn't detect the dartboard propelly. (IMPORTANT: I can't use machine learning to fix this problem)

I already am able to detect the dartboard with houghCircles but only when it's infront of the cam when the off angle happens it doesn't work anymore.

In the future I'm gonna need to detect darts on the dartboard but thats a future problem.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_dartboard(frame):
    # Convert the frame to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Blur the image to remove noise
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Use adaptive thresholding to get a binary image
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Find contours in the binary image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Remove small contours
    contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 10000]

    # Find the largest contour with a suitable area and perimeter
    largest_contour = None
    largest_area = 0
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        if area > largest_area and area > 1000 and perimeter > 1000:
            largest_contour = contour
            largest_area = area

    # Check if a suitable contour was found
    if largest_contour is not None:
        # Calculate the center of the contour
        M = cv2.moments(largest_contour)
        center = (int(M['m10'] / M['m00']), int(M['m01'] / M['m00']))

        # Draw the detected contour and its center on the frame
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [largest_contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    return frame

# Create a VideoCapture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture each frame from the video(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Process the frame
    processed_frame = detect_dartboard(frame)

    # Display the processed frame
    cv2.imshow('Processed Frame', processed_frame)

    # Exit the loop if the 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()

# Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is my code that I'm currently using. (I'm using a printed image of a dartboard currently because my irl one still needs to arrive)

Comment: have any example data?

Comment: @Him [Video](https://youtu.be/52r5S33UbT4) If you mean a video of the problem then yes (in the video it never detected the circle but sometimes is does poorly) and if you mean data that compare the detection and the data then no.

Comment: I mean it would be helpful to see what your algorithm currently outputs that you feel is incorrect.  You should include it in your question.

Comment: Post a single frame of the video so others can test more easily and your output for that frame.  You should try to rectify the image to a face on view so that HoughCircles works better.

Comment: Please take a picture of original dart board, not on white paper or maybe on white paper.